# UIScrollView without AutoLayout shows horizontal scroll Indicator in iOS 6 but not in iOS 7

Tags: uiscrollview, ios7, indicator

I spent several days trying to see the working UIScrollView horizontal scroll indicator (without AutoLayout) on iOS7 (on iPad). But without success.

Has anyone fixed such bug?

My project is simple and running iOS5 and iOS6 without troubles.

I found out, that on iOS7 height of the scroll indicator image is always zero:

```
UIImageView * scrollBar = [[scrollView subviews] lastObject];
if (scrollBar != nil)
{
    PrintRect(@"FRAME", scrollBar.frame);
    PrintRect(@"BOUNDS", scrollBar.bounds);
}
```

Result for iOS7:

```
FRAME x:0.000000 y:54.000000 w:338.000000 h:0.000000
BOUNDS x:0.000000 y:0.000000 w:338.000000 h:0.000000
```

but for iOS6:

```
FRAME x:0.000000 y:47.000000 w:338.000000 h:7.000000
BOUNDS x:0.000000 y:0.000000 w:338.000000 h:7.000000
```

So the height scroll bar image on iOS7 is equal to zero.
It's possible to change the height, but only for a quick time because during drugging the height becames zero again.

Comment: Can you show your codes ? what is the `contentSize` and the dimension of the `UIScrollView` ?

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on something similar. I am doing the CS193P course on iTunes and there was this `scrollView` exercise - Imaginarium. Basically it's just a `UIImageView` embedded in a `UIScrollView`. I was having the same problem that the scroll indicators were not being displayed (with `Autolayout` turned off)

I looked up the header file for UIScrollView in the documentation and there is this property in `scrollView` called `scrollIndicatorInsets`:

The distance the scroll indicators are inset from the edge of the scroll view.

```
@property(nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets scrollIndicatorInsets
```

It goes on to say that the default value is `UIEdgeInsetsZero`!! So I created a `UIEdgeInset` using `UIEdgeInsetsMake` (see documentation). Then in `viewDidLoad` I set this `UIEdgeInsets` to be my scrollView's scrollIndicatorInsets, after which my indicators appeared when I scrolled.

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: @zero323
Thank you, but unfortunatly, this way I'm able to change the scroll indicator horizontal position, but not height.

Comment: AntonS You should thank @Azzaknight. My input is only some formatting.

Comment: @Azzaknight Thank you, but this way I'm able to change the scroll indicator horizontal position for iOS6 application, but height of the scroll indicator image still the same and equals zero in iOS7 application.